# Can you help take the derivative of this equation?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find d/d(vIN) for this equation and I'm struggling to do it and wolfram alpha seems to give an incorrect equation:

[image: equation]

Answer (score 0):

The expression you wrote seems to correspond to the roots of the implicit function

$$F=\frac K 2 V^2_{out}-\left(\frac 1{R_s}+K(V_{in}-V_T) \right)V_{out}+\frac K2(V_{in}-V_T)^2=0$$ So, use the implicit function theorem computing $$F'_{V_{out}}=\frac {dF}{dV_{out}}\qquad\text{and}\qquad F'_{V_{in}}=\frac {dF}{dV_{in}}$$ and use $$\frac {dV_{out}}{dV_{in}}=-\frac {F'_{V_{in}}}{F'_{V_{out}} }$$